# class modules vs classes in .net

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, vb6, vb6-migration

I am in the process of upgrading some 5k lines of vb6 code to vb.net (originally what I thought would be an easy job). The vb6 code has been  heavily written in an OO style using class modules (`.cls` files).

Should I keep this file extension  (if possible) or should I attempt to replicate the `.cls` file in a class file (`.vb` file) in vb.net

What are the differences between a **class-module** file and a **class** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- VB6 `Class Modules` (.cls) are effectively equivalent to `Classes` in
  .Net (with quite a few syntactical differences)
- VB6 `Modules` (.bas) are equivalent to `Modules` in .Net (with some syntactical differences)

Both Classes and Modules in .Net have to have the .vb extension, so you can't keep your .cls files as they are, you will have to translate/re-write the VB6 code into .Net

Comment: Great, clear and to the point. Thanks, will accept when the timer runs out.